# Got error 'repetition-operator operand invalid' from regexp - mysql

Tags: php, mysql, regex

When i try to use the following regexp in sql i am getting the error.

```
 [0-9]{10,}|(?:[\+\(]|1\-)\s*[0-9]+([ \.\(\)\-/x]+[0-9]{2,})+[0-9]
```

Please let me know the mistake i have done on this.

Error i am getting is,

> 1139 Got error 'repetition-operator operand invalid' from regexp

Comment: Not sure what limitations MySQL regex have, but I don't see anything wrong here right away. Can you show us some example code you have where you define and use this expression?

Answer (score 3):

See bug http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=399

\+ is getting seen as repetition-operator
So this fails too:

```
mysql> select 'fred' regexp('?[\+]'); 
ERROR 1139 (42000): Got error 'repetition-operator operand invalid' from regexp
```

Comment: The error is coming because of ?: can you please tell me how to use ?: in mysql regexp?

Comment: Try changing it to ^ and I believe it should still get the error